# Python AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm currently encountering an error with my code, and I have no idea why. I originally thought it was because I couldn't save a csv file with hyphens in it, but that turns out not to be the case. Does anyone have any suggestions to what might be causing the problem. My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

query_set = ["points-per-game"]

for query in query_set:
    url = 'https://www.teamrankings.com/ncaa-basketball/stat/' + str(query)
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    print(df_list)

    df_list.to_csv(str(query) + "stat.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: the error is pretty clear - you are attempting to call `.to_csv` to a python list (which would obviously fail)

Comment: as stated below you need to call the dataframe element from the list. Also, no need for `html = requests.get(url).content` as pandas `.read_html()` has the capablities to request the html. simply can do `df_list = pd.read_html(url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `read_html()` method returns a list of dataframes, not a single dataframe:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

You'll want to loop through your df_list and run to_csv on each entry, like so:

```
import pandas as pd import requests

query_set = ["points-per-game"]

for query in query_set:
    url = 'https://www.teamrankings.com/ncaa-basketball/stat/' + str(query)
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    print(df_list)

    for current_df in df_list:
      current_df.to_csv(str(query) + "stat.csv", encoding="utf-8")
      print(current_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `pd.read_html` returns a list of DataFrames found in the HTML source. Use `df_list[0]` to get the DataFrame which is the first element of this list.